# access modifiers for IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in C#, just a question on IEnumerable and IEnumerable. I saw some code like this:

```
public class ShoppingCart : IEnumerable<Product>
{
   public IEnumerator<Product> GetEnumerator()
   {
      return Products.GetEnumerator(); 
   }
   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() //why 'public' is not needed?
   {
      return GetEnumerator();
   }
}
```

I understand that first method is to implement the `IEnumerator<Product>` and second method is to implement `IEnumerator` since `IEnumerator` inherits from `IEnumerator<Product>`, but I don't understand why no 'public' access modifier is required for the second method? the first method does have 'public'.
And since both interfaces have same method signature, so we can see that second method use interfacename.methodname as explicit interface implementation, but why first method doesn't need this? shouldn't it be:

```
public IEnumerator<Product>.GetEnumerator()
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: In a sense, its not all that public at all. The only way to access it is through that interface

Comment: @BradleyDotNET  even if I put the public keyword in front of second method, the compiler throws errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all comes down to the differences between implicit and explicit implementation of interface members.

- An explicitly implemented member doesn't appear on the object unless the object is cast to the implemented interface. If you want someone to be able to call `new ShoppingCart().GetEnumerator()`, you must have a `GetEnumerator` method that's not an explicit implementation. Supposing it abides by the contract of one of the implemented interfaces, it'll implicitly implement the method on that interface. In this case, you must specify an access modifier because the main point of declaring the member is to make it available from this specific class. The modifier must be at least as permissive as the interface it's implementing (and it may be more permissive).
- When explicitly implementing an interface member, you don't need to (and in fact, you cannot) specify the visibility (e.g. `public`) because the visibility is already set by the interface itself. Since the object must be cast to that interface in order to access that member, the member isn't considered to have any visibility beyond the visibility of the interface.

The first method in your code *could have been* explicitly implemented, like this:

```
IEnumerator<Product> IEnumerable<Product>.GetEnumerator()
{
    return Products.GetEnumerator();
}
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IEnumerable<Product>)this).GetEnumerator();
}
```

But whoever created that class chose to implement it implicitly so it would be available without having to first cast ShoppingList to an `IEnumerable<Product>`. Notice how this made the other method's implementation easier, because they could simply call `this.GetEnumerator()` without having to cast `this` first.

But since the second method only differs from the first by return type, it's impossible to implement both methods implicitly. It's common practice to implement the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface explicitly in these cases.

Comment: But if I modify the first method to use explicit implementation just like the second method as `IEnumerator<Product>.GetEnumerator() `, the compiler still throw an error?

Comment: @amjad: That's only because the other method is trying to call `GetEnumerator()` on the `ShoppingList` class. If it's explicitly implemented, it's no longer available on that class: you can only access it by casting the object first. See my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm still confused on the casting stuff, according to you code, isn't that 'this' refer to ShoppingList instance, then the GetEnumerator is definitely available, why it need to be casted to access that method?

Comment: @amjad: That's because in the code I posted the `GetEnumerator()` method is only implemented explicitly. That means its visibility is restricted to code that's working with this object cast as an `IEnumerable<Product>`. There is no longer any `GetEnumerator()` method declared on the `ShoppingCart` class itself. For example, `nameof(ShoppingCart.GetEnumerator)` works fine in the original code where GetEnumerator is implicitly implemented, but it won't resolve if all implementations are explicit.